# For each node //episode, get denormalized parent //Season, using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to translate some XML into a flat, denormalized tabular format, using multiple Xpath statements, each of which defines a table column.

Given a sample XML:

```
<shows>
  <show name="foo">
    <season no="1">
      <episode no="1" name="s01e01" />
      <episode no="2" name="s01e02" />
      <episode no="3" name="s01e03" />
    </season>
    <season no="2">
      <episode no="1" name="s02e01" />
      <episode no="2" name="s02e01" />
    </season>
  </show>
  <!-- ... -->
</shows>
```

I can easily extract the individual episodes, but I cannot seem to tie the season or show to each episode.

I have tried:

1. using `..`:

   - Show:    `//show/season/episode/../../@name`
   - Season:  `//show/season/episode/../@no`
   - Episode: `//show/season/episode/@no`
   - Title:   `//show/season/episode/@name`
2. using axes (e.g. `parent` or `ancestor`):

   - Show:    `//show/season/episode/ancestor::show/@name`
   - Season:  `//show/season/episode/parent::season/@no`
   - Episode: `//show/season/episode/@no`
   - Title:   `//show/season/episode/@name`

...but both return me the distinct/unique list of seasons (which don't correlate season to episode):

```
Show        Season   Episode  Title
----------- -------- -------- --------
foo         1        1        s01e01
            2        2        s01e02
                     3        s01e03
                     1        s02e01
                     2        s02e02
```

...whereas I am looking for the denormalized set:

```
Show        Season   Episode  Title
----------- -------- -------- --------
foo         1        1        s01e01
foo         1        2        s01e02
foo         1        3        s01e03
foo         2        1        s02e01
foo         2        2        s02e02
```

**What Xpath could I use to form an expanded set of the seasons, i.e. how would I get the `season no` attribute to repeat for each `episode` element?**

<sub>FWIW, I am using the `=IMPORTXML(url, xpath)` function within Google Spreadsheets to build my table.  I can already solve the issue for that application using an App Script (indeed, anything which supports variables and nested loops can manage it), but I'm more interested as to the specifics of Xpath, as I've noticed the same behaviour in other Xpath implementations.</sub>

Comment: You should tag this answer with Google Sheets and add a link to a specific Sheets page, or include the actual formula code you are using.

Comment: XPath expressions select _sets_ of nodes (with no duplicates), not _lists_. If you can reach the same node by two different "routes" through the XPath expression it will still be included only once in the result set.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I covered the specific Google Sheets issue over at webapps.stackexchange.com -- I was more interested in whether the 'distinct' behaviour was the norm for all Xpath

Comment: Then your question should ask exactly this - because as it stands now, it asks for a specific XPath solution, not an explanation of its workings in general.